# How can I fix my inventory in DayZ?

Tags: dayz-2012

I am using the DayZ launcher, but I cannot right click to equip the flashlight & bandages once I am in game.

Is this some sort of side effect of using the launcher?

Comment: Have you tried both left click and right click? This isn't a problem with the launcher, but with the game itself. Make sure you have the bag selected when you attempt to right click either item.

Comment: I have tried but after watching few videos seen others having the same issue where the "use item" tab drops behind inventory/bag...serious takes minutes to simply bandage self or equip light/hatchet type items...belt item removal is largest issue i have faced making this game all the more challenging.

Comment: I believe this is just lag, due to the character server being overloaded. I don't think there is really anything you can do to solve this.